# In which order are the files in a directory read in by default by Java listFiles()?

Tags: java, java-io

I made the following program, which reads all files in the directory. 
All file names are composed of numbers (e.g. 10023134.txt).

```
File dir = new File(directoryPath);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File file : files)
    try {
        if ( !file.exists())
            continue;
        else if (file.isFile()) {
            // some process
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

I would like to know in what order the files in the directory are read by default.

It seems the program read the files by neither numerical order nor order of creation date.

Comment: why don't you print the file names and see for yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()):

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

If you want them sorted, you'll have to sort them yourself.

Note that if you sort using the default ordering, you'll still get different results depending on your OS. Again from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#compareTo(java.io.File)):

> The ordering defined by this method depends upon the underlying
>   system. On UNIX systems, alphabetic case is significant in comparing
>   pathnames; on Microsoft Windows systems it is not.

Answer (score 5):

The order of the files is likely by OS default (or listing neutral) order and will depend on the how the OS returns a list of files back to Java.

There is no guarantee of the order that the files may be returned in.

You could use `Arrays.sort(T[] Comparator<? super T> c)` to sort the list after you have read it.

Comment: while this is likely true for most implementations of the method, there is nothing in the docs guaranteeing that behavior

Comment: @SillyFreak This is true, this also nothing in the Docs to say one way or another, other then that the order is not guaranteed

Answer (score 3):

The files are sorted in the natural order of your operating system. It may be the creation order.
If you want the list to be sorted, you can call

```
File[] files = Arrays.sort(dir.listFiles())
```

For another sort order, feel free to use your own `Comparator`.
Regards.